# Create a new column by extracting the smallest tuple from a data frame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column that contains tuples. I would like to create a new column that extracts the smallest tuple from the tuple column.

What I have tried so far

`mydataframe['min_values'] = mydataframe['tuple_column'].apply(lambda x: min(x))`

This above approach seems to work when I have at least 2 tuples, but it fails when I only have one tuple e.g. 5 in the example below. Could you guys please suggest a method that would help me accomplish this task in a better manner?

**Example and desired result**

| Tuple Column | New Column |
| --- | --- |
| (1,2,3,5) | 1 |
| (10,11) | 10 |
| (5) | 5 |

Thanks

Comment: What is the "*smallest*" tuple? number of values? min tuple value?

Comment: oh good question, what I meant is the smallest value tuple. e.g. (1,2,3,4) - here 1 would be the smallest tuple, in (10, 15, 20) - 10 is the smallest one.

Comment: You last row is not a tuple, a tuple is defined by a comma, not the parentheses (`1, 2` is a tuple, `(1,)` is a tuple, `(1)` is not a tuple) ;)

Comment: maybe thats the issue, the error message I get is 
'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Yes, if you try to construct the DataFrame, you should not see the parentheses for the last row (unless you have strings of course…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(5)` is not a tuple, this is `5`. Use [`numpy.min`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin) that handles scalar values as input:

```
import numpy as np
df['New Column'] = df['Tuple Column'].apply(np.min)
```

Output:

```
   Tuple Column  New Column
0  (1, 2, 3, 5)           1
1      (10, 11)          10
2             5           5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `map()`

```
df['Tuple Column'].map(lambda x: min(x) if isinstance(x,tuple) else x)
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    3
2    5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.applymap(lambda x:pd.Series(eval(x)).min())
```

Output:

```
0    1
1    3
2    5
```